# ORA-00604 error while batch insertion inside TransactionScope

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net, transactionscope, batch-insert

I am trying to batch insert 100k+ items to my Oracle db using ADO.NET inside a TransactionScope. Like this:

```
using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope())
{
    while(/* Pagination logic - send insertion command on every 250 items */)
    {
        using (OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(query, connection))
        {
            command.ArrayBindCount = 250;

            //Add parameters
            command.Parameters.Add(":BLAH", OracleDbType.Long);
            command.Parameters[0].Value = LUC.ToArray();

            command.ExecuteNonQuery(); //Error occurs here after N-times inside while
        }
    }
    transaction.Complete();
}
```

For items lower than this (10k-30k) transaction is completed successfully.
However for higher items (like 100k) I get **ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level %s**.

If I remove TransactionScope altogether, I don't get any error with any item size, it just works.

How can I make TransactionScope work with huge number of items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, it was a transactional timeout problem.

After I increased the timeout, I have inserted my list successfully:

```
using (TransactionScope transaction = 
         new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, 
                 new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0))) //30 minute timeout limit
```